# Is there a way to generate a *.Designer.cs file for legacy form?

Tags: c#, winforms

We're dealing with a legacy form, where the code that usually goes in the `*.Designer.cs` file is located in the same file as the constructor instead.

[image: The usual Designer-related code, located directly in AboutForm.cs]

There isn't even a `*.Designer.cs` file for this form:

[image: AboutForm.cs doesn't have a designer, while ShellForm.cs does]

Is there any way to generate a `*.Designer.cs` file from this file?

Comment: You could manually create it and move the parts pertinent to it or create a new form and simple move the parts related to it and delete the old one. But automatically I don't think there is one. Not having the Designer.cs file is not an issue, it just means the GUI code is within the AboutForm.cs

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to manually create your missing *FormName*.Designer.cs file as suggested by Prix, you'll need to modify your .csproj Project file as well to create the connection between your *FormName*.cs and your re-created *FormName*.Designer.cs

```
...
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
  </Compile>
  <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
  </Compile>
...
</ItemGroup>
```